# How to handle token expirations in a Spring OAuth SSO Authorization server?

Tags: spring, facebook, oauth, spring-security, single-sign-on

I have been following a [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) to create a Spring SSO application which uses Facebook for authentication but creates its own access tokens to secure back-end resources.

The sample application creates a user on first login and stores the user's facebook token for further use (getting data from facebook later on).

My question is that how do I handle token expirations? When the facebook token expires, how do we setup spring security to refresh it?  What about our application's token expiration?

You can find my sample project [here](https://github.com/hazim1093/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/oauth-test/auth-server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app in the tutorial only uses the token for authentication (i.e. it uses it once when the user logs in to get the user's personal details), so it's highly unlikely to expire in the time it is being used. Having said that, the `OAuth2RestOperations` instance that is used to carry out that single request is capable of refreshing the token on its own (if the provider sent it a refresh token and allows the access token to be refreshed by your client).